# rdiff-backup command to restore

Tags: linux, backup-restoration, incremental-backup

Let say i have a source directory which contains The contents /foo/a /foo/b(These are the files in a directory on a remote system)

using rdiff command i make a backup as

```
 rdiff-backup root@192.168.254.111::/foo backups
```

And a,b are now present in my backups directory.And then i delete file a from the remote system and again i do a sync so my local directory has the file b only.

My question is that how do i restore file a if the deletion and sync is done on the same day

Thanks..

Answer (score 1):

This command:

```
rdiff-backup -r 1D root@192.168.254.111::/foo/a backups/a
```

should restore your file as of "*1 day ago*". Is this what you're looking for?

You can also use `1B` instead of `1D` for last backup session.

More about the time formats: [rdiff-backup man pages](http://rdiff-backup.nongnu.org/rdiff-backup.1.html)

And some [examples of usage](http://rdiff-backup.nongnu.org/examples.html).